# Avoid the status bar (footer) from disappearing in a GUI when reducing the size of the screen

Tags: python, tkinter

I have developed a quite large GUI using tkinter.

Everything is working great when resizing, except for the case of reducing a lot the height of the window. All the frames are placed using 'pack()'.

The basic vertical structure of the GUI is (ordered from top to bottom):

- Toolbar frame

  ```
  self.frame_Toolbar=Frame(self.root, bg=colorBackground)
  self.frame_Toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
  ```
- Middle frame containing all the basic information

  ```
  self.frame_Middle=Frame(self.root)
  self.frame_Middle.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
  ```
- Status bar

  ```
  self.frame_Status=Frame(self.root, bg=colorStatus, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)
  self.frame_Status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
  ```

The middle frame is enlarged if the window is resized, which is great since it is what I want.

The issue is that when reducing a lot the height of the window, the status bar disappears because the middle frame adapts to the internal widgets. However, I would like that both the status bar and toolbar would be maintained and the middle frame would reduce as much as needed even if hiding some widgets.

To sum up, I would like that both the toolbar and status bar have like a minimum height.

Is that possible?

Edit: I add a functional MCVE code with the same error

```
# Import graphical interface
from tkinter import *

 # Fixed window
root_fw=Tk()

# Toolbar
frame_Toolbar=Frame(root_fw, bg='red', height=50)
frame_Toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

# Middle 
frame_Middle=Frame(root_fw, bg='blue', height=300)
frame_Middle.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

# Status bar
frame_Status=Frame(root_fw, bg='green', bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, height=20)
frame_Status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

root_fw.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you provide a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduce your problem please? It would be easier for us to test the code and provide an answer.

Comment: I have modified the question providing a MCVE with the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once all of the widgets are at their minimum size, when you shrink the window tkinter must start reducing the size of one or more widgets. It does this in the order that widgets appear in the stacking order. Simply put, it starts removing space from the last widget that was packed.

So, the short answer is to pack the statusbar before you pack the middle widget. Generally speaking, a GUI will have one "hero" widget that takes up most of the space; it is this window that should be packed last so that the other widgets will not be clipped when the window is resized.

My recommendation is to always separate widget creation from widget layout, and to group layout together. I find this practice makes layout problems much easier to solve. I would therefore modify your code to look like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root_fw=Tk()

frame_Toolbar=Frame(root_fw, bg='red', height=50)
frame_Middle=Frame(root_fw, bg='blue', height=300)
frame_Status=Frame(root_fw, bg='green', bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, height=20)

frame_Toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
frame_Status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
frame_Middle.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

root_fw.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sir, perfect answer: minimum changes on the code and some useful advices. Thank you!

Comment: thx for the demo code. It took me more than one read (on different days) to understand that it is a solution, and an elegant one too. I'm using pygubu-designer and my workaround was to use place for the status bar and add a padding to frame above it, which is ugly because the padding is applied to both sides. Then I realized from your code that I should move the status bar up in the designer so it gets packed first, but make it packed to the bottom instead.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to switch to the `Grid` layout because you can configure rows and columns. The minimum height of a row can be set with the `minsize` option of the `rowconfigure` method.

In addition, you need to configure the middle row to resize with the window by setting its `weight` to 1 and finally you can set a minimum size for the widow to be at least big enough to show both bars.

```
from tkinter import *

# Fixed window
root_fw = Tk()
# resize row 1 and column 0 with window
root_fw.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root_fw.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# set minimum height for row 0 and 2
root_fw.rowconfigure(0, minsize=50)
root_fw.rowconfigure(2, minsize=20)
# set window min size
root_fw.minsize(70, 70)

# Toolbar
frame_Toolbar = Frame(root_fw, bg='red', height=50, width=200)
frame_Toolbar.grid(row=0, sticky="ew")

# Middle 
frame_Middle = Frame(root_fw, bg='blue', height=300, width=200)
frame_Middle.grid(row=1, sticky="ewsn")

# Status bar
frame_Status = Frame(root_fw, bg='green', bd=1, relief="sunken", height=20, width=200)
frame_Status.grid(row=2, sticky="ew")

root_fw.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I vote up since it perfectly works, but I prefer Bryan Oakley answer since less changes are needed and I can preserve the 'pack()' method.

Comment: I understand, no problem. I'm more used to `grid` than `pack`.